Unable to download artifact(s): Artifact not found for name: java-app
I've been stuck for a while now on the issue I'm having where when I want to deploy my java app to Azure. It doesn't recognise the artifact that I build in a previous workflow run. these are the build and deploy files:
name: Build JAR app - kobeodbCR-backend

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: "17"

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: "${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar"

name: Deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - kobeodbCR-backend

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Build JAR app - kobeodbCR-backend"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: "kobeodbCR-backend"
          slot-name: "Production"
          package: "*.jar"
          publish-profile: ${{ ... }}

and this is the error im getting:

deploy
Unable to download artifact(s): Artifact not found for name: java-app Please ensure that your artifact is not expired and the artifact was uploaded using a compatible version of toolkit/upload-artifact. For more information, visit the GitHub Artifacts FAQ: https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/packages/artifact/docs/faq.md

Why is this happening?
The build workflow completes successfully, and the artifact is created, but the deploy workflow fails after give or take 10 seconds.
I've tried a few different things, mostly recommendations from chatGPT, but none of them have successfully worked.

Could you try adding the run-id input to your actions/download-artifact@v4 usage in the second workflow? It might be something like this run-id: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.id }}.

@GuiFalourd i tried it but it doesnt work..

What error message did you get? Could you update the question with this tentative?

I had a similar issue, i was using different versions on upload and download actions.Finally Worked with version match on both upload and download.

It's not really an answer to the question. The answer must be clear and reproducible. When you will have enought points, it's better to comment the question instead.

Also had an issue due to versions mismatch. Thanks, you answer saved my day!

you need to specify run id in the download-artifact step to accomplish this as these workflows running independently
- name: Download Artifacts 
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
  with:
    name: java-app
    run-id: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.id }}
    github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}


There is no scope/context in the workflowB. You will need to to generate a token based on a github app that you need to add to your repo. Something like this:
- name: Get GitHub App token
  id: get-token
  uses: actions/create-github-app-token@v1
  with:
    owner: 'me'
    app-id: ${{ secrets.APPLICATION_ID }}
    private-key: ${{ secrets.APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY }}

- name: Download artifact from build job
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
  with:
    run-id: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.id }}
    github-token: ${{ github.token }}
    name: java-app

To create the github app here is the doc: https://docs.github.com/es/apps/creating-github-apps/about-creating-github-apps/about-creating-github-apps
An alternative much simplier would be to fuse both worklows and set an input parameter so you can decide when you upload or not the artefact. Example:
name: Build JAR app - kobeodbCR-backend

on:
 push:
 branches:
   - main
 workflow_dispatch:
   inputs:
     goToPRO:
     required: false
     type: string
     default: 'false'
     description: 'Should it go to PRO?'     

jobs:
 build:
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4

  - name: Set up Java version
    uses: actions/setup-java@v1
    with:
      java-version: "17"

  - name: Build with Maven
    run: mvn clean install

  - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
    id: deploy-to-webapp
    uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
    if: ${{inputs.goToPRO == 'true'}}
    with:
      app-name: "kobeodbCR-backend"
      slot-name: "Production"
      package: "*.jar"
      publish-profile: ${{ ... }}


I was having some troubles with the name of the artifact. In the docs, it says that the width: Name is not necessary. You could only specify the path, and it would name the artifact as 'artifact '.
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          path: 'C:\Users\hi\Desktop\downloads\'
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          path: ./my-artifact/

